# Max value from 4 json source url

Tags: javascript, json

I have fetch some value from json url, with this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function price(){
 
    $.getJSON('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker', function(data){
      document.getElementById('PoloniexLastNXT').innerHTML = (data.BTC_NXT.last);
      document.getElementById('PoloniexBidNXT').innerHTML = (data.BTC_NXT.highestBid);
      document.getElementById('PoloniexAskNXT').innerHTML = (data.BTC_NXT.lowestAsk);
    });

    $.getJSON('trade/libs/bittrex.php?i=nxt', function(data){
      document.getElementById('BittrexLastNXT').innerHTML = (data.Bittrex);
      document.getElementById('BittrexBidNXT').innerHTML = (data.BittrexBid);
      document.getElementById('BittrexAskNXT').innerHTML = (data.BittrexAsk);
    });

    $.getJSON('trade/libs/hitbtc2.php?i=NXT', function(data){
      document.getElementById('HitbtcLastNXT').innerHTML = (data.hitbtc);
      document.getElementById('HitbtcBidNXT').innerHTML = (data.hitbtcbid);
      document.getElementById('HitbtcAskNXT').innerHTML = (data.hitbtcask);
    });

    $.getJSON('https://vip.bitcoin.co.id/api/nxt_btc/ticker', function(data) {
      document.getElementById('priceLastNXT').innerHTML = (data.ticker.last);
      document.getElementById('priceLashBuyNXT').innerHTML = (data.ticker.buy);
      document.getElementById('priceLashSellNXT').innerHTML = (data.ticker.sell);
      document.title = "NXT " + (data.ticker.last);
    });
}

setInterval(price, 3000);

});
```

can I do this

```js
function getMax(array){
    return Math.max.apply(Math,array);
}

var NxtBid = document.getElementById("PoloniexBidNXT");
var NxtBid2 = document.getElementById("BittrexBidNXT");
var NxtBid3 = document.getElementById("HitbtcBidNXT");
var NxtBid4 = document.getElementById("priceLashBuyNXT");
var NxtBid5 = [NxtBid, NxtBid2, NxtBid3, NxtBid4];
var NxtBid6 = getMax(NxtBid5);

document.getElementById("NxtBidMax").innerHTML = NxtBid6;
```

I want to set low price and hi price from PoloniexLastNXT, BittrexLastNXT,HitbtcLastNXT, priceLastNXT.someone can help me

Comment: You want to set _what_ to the low and high prices? This question isn't very clear...

Answer (score 0):

For Poloneix you can use assuming you have elements for "PoloniexLowNXT" and "PoloniexHighNXT",

```
$.getJSON('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker', function(data){
      document.getElementById('PoloniexLastNXT').innerHTML = (data.BTC_NXT.last);
      document.getElementById('PoloniexBidNXT').innerHTML = (data.BTC_NXT.highestBid);
      document.getElementById('PoloniexAskNXT').innerHTML = (data.BTC_NXT.lowestAsk);
      document.getElementById('PoloniexLowNXT').innerHTML = (data.BTC_NXT.low24hr);
      document.getElementById('PoloniexHighNXT').innerHTML = (data.BTC_NXT.high24hr);
    });
```

Comment: I want to compare from some market to see lower price

Answer (score 0):

You could try Promise.all and do a forEach on the results. Instead of repeating the implementation code you could create an array of settings and loop over it to get the result and process them:

```
const settings = [
  [
    "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker",//url
    ["#PoloniexLastNXT","#PoloniexBidNXT","#PoloniexAskNXT"],//elements to set
    [//how to get value
      data=>data.BTC_NXT.last,
      data=>data.BTC_NXT.highestBid,
      data=>data.BTC_NXT.lowestAsk
    ]

  ]
  //others
];

Promise.all(
  settings.map(
    ([url],index)=>
      $.getJSON(setting(url))
      .then(
        data=>[data,settings[index]]
      )
  )
).then(
  results=>{
    var lowestLast=Infinity,highestLast=-Infinity;
    results.forEach(
      ([data,[url,querySelectors,getters]])=>{
        querySelectors.forEach(
          (querySelector,index)=>
            document.querySelector(querySelector).innerHTML=getters[index](data)
        )
        const last = getters[0](data);
        if(last<lowestLast){
          lowestLast=last;
        }
        if(last>highestLast){
          highestLast=last;
        }
      }
    )
    return [lowestLast,highestLast];
  }
).then(
  ([lowest,highest])=>{
    console.log("lowest:",lowest,"highest:",highest);
  }
).catch(
  err=>console.warn("something went wrong:",err)
);
```

**update**

If you want to continue using your own repetitive implementation then you can get min and max in this way:

```
const numbers = [
  new Number(trim(document.getElementById("PoloniexBidNXT").innerText)),
  new Number(trim(document.getElementById("BittrexBidNXT").innerText)),
  new Number(trim(document.getElementById("HitbtcBidNXT").innerText)),
  new Number(trim(document.getElementById("priceLashBuyNXT".innerText)))
];
const lowest = Math.max.apply(null,numbers);
const highest = Math.min.apply(null,numbers);
```

Comment: how use it, can you explain more

Comment: @SiriusKuddo You can start by adding `others` in the data, then try it and come back when you have a specific question about something. I updated the answer since there was a small bug

Comment: I have update my question, can you help me.Im stag on 'Nan' Result

Comment: @SiriusKuddo Updated answer.